# Property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to convert this JavaScript file to Typescript:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from './Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';
import SettingsDropdown from "./SettingsDropdown";
import BillingDropdown from "./BillingDropdown";

function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState({
    settings: false,
    billing: false
  });

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

  const onMouseEnter = (name: String) => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
      setDropdown(state => ({ ...state, [name]: false }));
    } else {
      setDropdown(state => ({ ...state, [name]: true }));
    }
  };

  const onMouseLeave = (name: String) => {
    setDropdown(state => ({ ...state, [name]: false }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav className='navbar'>
        <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
          Merchant Hub
          <i class='fab fa-firstdraft' />
        </Link>
        <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
          <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
        </div>
        <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li
              className="nav-item"
              onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter.bind(this, 'settings')}
              onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave.bind(this, 'settings')}
          >
            <Link
                to="/settings"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
            >
              Settings <i className="fas fa-caret-down" />
            </Link>
            {dropdown.settings && <SettingsDropdown />}
          </li>
          <li
              className="nav-item"
              onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter.bind(this, 'billing')}
              onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave.bind(this, 'billing')}
          >
            <Link to="/billing" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
              Billing <i className="fas fa-caret-down" />
            </Link>
            {dropdown.billing && <BillingDropdown />}
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link
                to='/support'
                className='nav-links'
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
            >
              Support
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link
              to='/developers'
              className='nav-links'
              onClick={closeMobileMenu}
            >
              Developers
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link
              to='/sign-up'
              className='nav-links-mobile'
              onClick={closeMobileMenu}
            >
              Profile
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Button />
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

I can't find how I can fix these lines:

`setDropdown(state => ({ ...state, [name]: false }));` - I get error `TS2464: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.`

`onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter.bind(this, 'settings')}` - get error `TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`

Do you know how I can fix these issues?

EDIT: I updated the code this way:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from './Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';
import SettingsDropdown from "./SettingsDropdown";
import BillingDropdown from "./BillingDropdown";

function Navbar() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState({
    settings: false,
    billing: false
  });

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);

  const onMouseEnter = (name: string) => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
      setDropdown(state => ({ ...state, [name]: false }));
    } else {
      setDropdown(state => ({ ...state, [name]: true }));
    }
  };

  const onMouseLeave = (name: string) => {
    setDropdown(state => ({ ...state, [name]: false }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav className='navbar'>
        <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
          Merchant Hub
          <i class='fab fa-firstdraft' />
        </Link>
        <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
          <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
        </div>
        <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li
              className="nav-item"
              onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter('settings')}
              onMouseLeave={() => onMouseLeave('settings')}
          >
            <Link
                to="/settings"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
            >
              Settings <i className="fas fa-caret-down" />
            </Link>
            {dropdown.settings && <SettingsDropdown />}
          </li>
          <li
              className="nav-item"
              onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter('billing')}
              onMouseLeave={() => onMouseLeave('billing')}
          >
            <Link to="/billing" className="nav-links" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
              Billing <i className="fas fa-caret-down" />
            </Link>
            {dropdown.billing && <BillingDropdown />}
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link
                to='/support'
                className='nav-links'
                onClick={closeMobileMenu}
            >
              Support
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <Link
              to='/developers'
              className='nav-links'
              onClick={closeMobileMenu}
            >
              Developers
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link
              to='/sign-up'
              className='nav-links-mobile'
              onClick={closeMobileMenu}
            >
              Profile
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Button />
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

For this line `<i class='fab fa-firstdraft' />` I get `TS2322: Type '{ class: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.   Property 'class' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'. Did you mean 'className'?` Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can just do this `onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter('settings')}` . Also it is a string without capital S .  `(name: string)`

Comment: `'String' !== 'string'` and it's unclear why you're trying to bind `this` at all in a function-based component.

Comment: Thanks, do you know also for this line: `onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter.bind(this, 'billing')}` how I need ot change it?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you can do this instead `onMouseEnter={() => onMouseEnter('billing')}`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post. I get now error for html tag attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `class` in React, use `className` instead.

Comment: Very strange the icon is not displayed.

Comment: That would probably be an issue with your setup. I don't use font awesome - so can't say much about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're using the String object type. Change `String` to `string`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can fix the latest problem?